# Get exact id to move gradient images

Tags: javascript

[image]I am finishing a swatch gradient project, and on the last part, which is getting a selected swatch image back in to the main  div to be edited (ie values changed,) then saved back to the same spot, which is the only div with and id of `bg-gradient`

I have already tried this selector with the delete  function and it works fine, however that deleted the entire swatch.

I want to get the `bg-gradient`, swap back to the main div (`#bodybg`) to edit/change values, and put back in the same location, which has the only id in the document `bg-gradient` (that's also the actual gradient).  My check code is not currently working, to find the value of the gradient to make sure we've got it, then swap it to the main div for editing. is below.

```js
editSwatch() {
  const elem = document.querySelector('#bg-gradient');
  //let main = document.getElementById('bodybg');
  const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
  console.log(style.backgroundImage).value;
},
```

In the image in console, the opened `col-md-3` is the swatch being edited and I want to add an attribute "gradient" to the child div where the gradient actually is, so can use it. 
The above console logged none, but it has a to right linear gradient, there is only the one id of `bg-gradient` in the document, and thats the one we are editing.

Ive also tried this

```js
editSwatch() {
  let elem = document.querySelector('.swatch#bg-gradient');
  elem.childElement.setAttribute("id","gradient");
},
```

but no good. The `editSwatch` function only handles the specific `col-md-3` seen open in the console.

Need to get this to finish the project, any tips welcome

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to show us more of your application, starting with some markup. It's difficult to visualize any sort of flow with so little information.

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure I understand the question. It will be the best if you can create a live demo (using codepen, codesandbox etc.), describe the test we should do in order to reproduce the issue what is the expected and the actual results.

Comment: Its actually just adding an id to the next div in, which contains the gradient, then manipulating that in to the main div to adjust the  hex values, so am trying to get the swatch gradient first. The one being edited is the only one in the document with the unique id of "bg-gradient" but that's the whole swatch, I want the gradient div inside (the bg) it so can swap it to the main one to edit. Ive got to give that a unique id also. Thanks (will be a bit complicated in Codepen as its in a whole Vue app.)

Comment: I actually did an almost identical project some time ago. You can check out the JSFiddle and see if it helps https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/ztL8k2wh/

Comment: OK will do thanks, I've already done the generator though, this is to swap the swatch back there to edit/change the values, then put it back in the swatch at same location.